# Why isn't vscode's intellisense finding my included file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, include-path

I tried to include the following:

```
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
```

But, I got this error:

```
boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp: No such file or directory
```

My c_cpp_properties.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",

            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}", "/mnt/c/Program Files/boost_1_62_0/boost_1_62_0"
            ],

            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode":"gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I use that same path in a makefile, and that works, so I don't know what the issue is. Is there a problem with the space in "Program Files"?

EDIT:
Literally just closing and reopening vscode fixes the issue...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the issue is that visual studio code doesn't update the error message: I had the same issue, but I noticed that just closing and reopening visual studio code fixes the problem.
See if it works.